# How to Get Share count of a picture while it says share_count is not a member of photo table

Tags: facebook-fql

I am using this query and trying to get share count of each pic but it returns an error.

```
SELECT link, comment_info, like_info, created, pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid 
    IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=20531316728)ORDER BY share_count desc
```

I do want to order the last 20 pictures with there share count. Can somebody help me how could I achieve this.

I am not writing an application. Just testing it in Graph API explorer v2.0 API in developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because there exists no `share_count` field in the FQL photo table.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

Comment: is there any other possibility to sort it out?

Comment: @rajkumar116 not in FQL you will have to run through each post in Graph API and check the sharedposts edge e.g. `10152203108461729/sharedposts`

Comment: ok but I couldn't still find the share count in it. Using this fql query I could get external links share count but internal link like fb page photo link data is not available. Can you check what the issue is?

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20url,like_count,%20total_count,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%20"http://bing.com"